# Backend architecture for REST API-backed backbone.js app?

Tags: rest, architecture, backbone.js, backend

We're looking to develop an internal productivity app which is fairly JS-heavy (think: editable fields which turn into dropdowns, a lot of dynamic adding and removing of sections on the current page, etc), and backed by a separate existing JSON REST API instead of a local database.

Having had bad experiences making dynamic pages with stock Rails+jQuery in the past, backbone.js seems like a more suitable tool. Question is, **what's a good way to structure the backend?** Rails seems like introducing unnecessary complexity as we won't be using ActiveRecord database models. Off the top of my head some other ideas are to use Sinatra, Node.js, or just plain HTML. Here are more considerations:

- It's by no means a single page app. There will be at least 3 different "non-hash" URL sections, so a routing engine would be helpful.
- We're a Ruby shop so anything Ruby-based will be easier to maintain.
- This app is unique in the sense that there will be little to no dynamic saving of data to the server. Page reloads are fine after sending data back. However, as mentioned above, there will be plenty of client-side manipulations before that.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is to build the backend as a pure api engine. Then use an MVC stack, as you're planning, on the client machines.

Daniel Doubrovkine is the CTO at Art.sy. He uses [Grape](https://github.com/intridea/grape) which rides on Rack.

Grape is a DSL for building APIs on Rack. In includes testability and handles the issues of multiple versions, authentication, access control and documentation.

His [presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/dblockdotorg/building-restful-apis-w-grape) about this. His [blog post](http://code.dblock.org/grape-020-released) about the latest version of Grape.

Comment: I knew my question wasn't very clear :) The REST API already exists and will be separate from this app. My question was what to use underneath backbone for _this_ app, not the app that powers the REST API.

Answer (score 1):

Backbone.js is fairly flexible; there's not much that's hard-wired.  That said, by default it looks for backend services that return models formatted as JSON.  So if you have a model with a property *foo*, then your service should return this:

```
{ "foo": "bar" }
```

Or for a collection:

```
[ { "foo": "bar1" }, { "foo": "bar2" } ]
```

Beyond that, you can specify what the URL looks like by defining a *urlRoot* property for each model type, then a *url* function that returns the URL for fetching a model given the *urlRoot* and the model's *cid* (client ID).

So in summary, if you implement a standard REST API that can work with raw JSON, then you should be fine.

Comment: So you're basically recommending me to use backbone.js with just plain HTML, and without an underlying web framework?

Answer (score 0):

You want to know about what to use underneath Backbone on the client?

Look into [marionette](https://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.marionette). [Tutorial](http://davidsulc.com/blog/2012/04/15/a-simple-backbone-marionette-tutorial/). [Blogging about it](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/12/16/composite-javascript-applications-with-backbone-and-backbone-marionette/).

Answer (score 0):

Since you say you have Ruby expertise, I would suggest you have a look at [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/). It looks like the easiest way to make a REST backend, especially for Ruby developers.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen it done successfully [with Middleman](http://tech.pollev.com/books/html5-apps/).

Basically Middleman compiles your static assets, which you can then send to a CDN or basic web server (such as Apache or Nginx). The 3 different pages you need are handled by having Middleman generate 3 separate HTML files.